# How to change the href through javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="div-id"><ul><li><a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">google</a> </li></ul></div>
```

How to change the href through javascript(not through getElementById,as it is not mentioned in html) or jquery?

Comment: What code have you got ? What did you already test ?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: What do you mean by _"not through getElementById,as it is not mentioned in html"_? `getElementById` is JavaScript.

Comment: you can try `$('ul li a').attr('href', 'www.stackoverflow.com')` but note that this wont work if there are multiple ul > li > a orders on the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To be more precise and make it work only for a particular anchor element

```
$("body").ready(function() {
  $("ul >li >a:contains("google").attr("href", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body").ready(function() {
  $("ul li a").attr("href", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> <li> <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">google</a> </li> </ul>
```

This is a simple way of doing it, but right now it applies this to all `Links` because you have no selector(class or id)

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById()` is not the only way to find an element in the document.  You can use fairly robust selectors with something like `document.querySelector()`.  As an extremely simple example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">google</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var element = document.querySelector('a');
  element.href = 'http://example.com';
</script>
```

Since, in the given markup, the link being targeted is the *only* `a` element in the DOM, the simple selector `'a'` will identify it.  In a more complex document, you can use more complex selectors.  For example:

```
document.querySelector('ul > li > a')
```

Or even:

```
document.querySelector('a[href="www.google.com"]')
```

Since you've also tagged the question with jQuery, you can use the same concept of selectors there as well.  Something like:

```
$('a').attr('href', 'http://example.com');
```

or:

```
$('a[href="www.google.com"]').attr('href', 'http://example.com');
```